# Fibonacci Sequences with same terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have two or more say different positive numbers **k** and **l**, .. **(with k less than l...)** and we add to k and l respectively a fibonacci sequence **(0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,....)**. We get therefore the sequence **(k, k+1, k+1, k+2, k+3, k+5, k+8, ....)** and **(l, l+1, l+1, l+2, l+3, l+5, l+8, ....)**. Similarly we can add another constant number to the same fib sequence etc... The two (or more) generated sequences, depending on the value **k** nad **l**, can have some terms of different index of course, the same value. What is the general condition for the generated fibonacci sequences to have some terms equal, and the question also extends to how many equal terms we get, depending on the distance **l-k** and l,k.  Thank you very much.

Comment: As you say, it depends on $l-k$.  If $l-k=1$, there are five solutions $k+1=l+0,k+1=l+0,k+2=l+1,k+2=l+1,k+3=l+2$.  If $l-k$ equals any other Fibonacci number, there are two solutions, for example $l-k=5$ then $l+3=k+8,l+8=k+13$.  Otherwise, there is one solution if $l-k$ is the difference of two Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it depends on $l−k$. If 
$l−k=1$, there are five solutions $$k+1=l+0,k+1=l+0,k+2=l+1,k+2=l+1,k+3=l+2$$
If $l-k=2$, there are $l+0=k+2,l+1=k+3,l+1=k+3,l+3=k+5$
If $l−k$ equals any other Fibonacci number, there are three solutions, for example $l−k=5$ then $l+0=k+5,l+3=k+8,l+8=k+13$.
If $l-k=F_n-1$, there are two solutions from counting 1 twice.
Otherwise, there is one solution if $l−k$ is the difference of two Fibonacci numbers.
These differences are $8-2;13-3,13-2;21-5,21-3,21-2;34-8,34-5,34-3,34-2;...$

Comment: Thank you very much Michael for a fast response! Yes very good! I guess you typed twice a solution for the case of l-k=2 . What if we l-k is not a fibonacci Fn-1 but another number such as 25 say?

Comment: What if the numbers are not Fibonacci but Lucas numbers do we get the same?

Comment: Once you get past $55$, the differences between Fibonacci numbers are too big to make up for a small difference of $25$.  I expect similar for Lucas numbers.  $0$ is not a Lucas number, so only two matches instead of three happen for $l-k=L_n$.  If $l-k=1$, there are three matches, and one if $l-k=L_a-L_b$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you sure. Well the general question arises. If we have any number, how many times can this number be a member of fibonacci sequences? Shifted ones...This is a harder one...For example...Number 11, can be present six times in total, in Fn+3, Fn+6, Fn+8, Fn+9, Fn+10, Fn+11. Can we generalise this?